# How to draw a 2d heatmap in polar coordinates with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a tibble with x and y components of a planar velocity vector.
If I draw a 2d heatmap with regular coordinates I get an expected result:

```
dyn_v %>% ggplot() + geom_bin2d(aes(vx, vy)) + scale_fill_viridis(trans = 'log10')
```

[image]

However, after applying `coord_polar` I get the following:

```
dyn_v %>% ggplot() + geom_bin2d(aes(vx, vy)) + scale_fill_viridis(trans = 'log10') + coord_polar()
```

[image]

There's obviously a mistake here - the hotspot should be in the center. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure I understand, you have a 2D plot of a square matrix, where  the center is the hotspot, you stretch it to be a circle, how do you imagine the new plot should look like? if the hotspot was still in the middle then it would again be your original plot by definition ( if all other variables stay the same).

Comment: If I transform cartesian coordinates to polar, then bins would be in the polar space, not cartesian space. So instead of {x1, x2, y1, y2}, a polar bin would be {r1, r2, phi1, phi2}. 
This way the heatspot goes to the center, because it lies in the region with small r.

Comment: Ah, got it. I'll answer my own question shortly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Got it. If you want to plot in the polar domain, you need to provide polar coordinates, simply applying `coord_polar` won't work.

So, if you have a tibble `T` with columns `x` and `y` and you want to plot a polar heatmap for them, then first transform `x` and `y` to `r` and `phi`, then pass those to `geom_bin2d`.

```
    (T
      %>% mutate(phi = (180/pi)*atan2(y, x))
      %>% mutate(r = sqrt(x*x + y*y))
      %>% ggplot(aes(phi, r))
      + geom_bin2d()
      + coord_polar()
      + scale_fill_viridis(trans = 'log10')
    )
```

[image]